# Wrapper(generic) pipeline function PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create something like a generic function using PL/SQL. The skeleton should be something like this below.

This is the code in the package specification

```
Type r_record
IS
  Record
  (
    col_1 Table.col_1 %Type ,
    col_2 Table.col_1 %Type );
Type T_table
IS
  TABLE OF r_record;
  CURSOR cur (p_i_a IN VARCHAR2, p_i_b IN VARCHAR2)
  IS
    SELECT col_1, col_2 
    FROM Table
    WHERE col_1= p_i_a 
    AND col_2= p_i_b 

  FUNCTION Get_result(
      p_i_a IN VARCHAR2,
      p_i_b IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN T_table Pipelined;
```

This is the code in the package body:

```
  FUNCTION Get_result(
      p_i_a IN VARCHAR2,
      p_i_b IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN T_table Pipelined
AS
    Vrow R_list;
      BEGIN
        FOR rec IN cursor(p_i_a, p_i_b)
        LOOP
          Vrow.col_1 := Rec.col_1 ;
          Vrow.col_2 := Rec.col_2 ;
          pipe row (vRow);
        END LOOP;
      END Get_result;
```

I need to create a lot of functions which have the same input parameters `p_i_a; p_i_b` and the output result depends only on them. My idea is the written code here to be as a generic so that the other function can use it. For example:

`Func1('aa', 'bb')` should call  FUNCTION `Get_result(p_i_a, p_i_b)`,

where `p_i_a = 'aa'` and `p_i_b = 'bb'`

and.....

`Func2('cc', 'dd')` should call  FUNCTION `Get_result(p_i_a, p_i_b)`,

where `p_i_a = 'cc'` and `p_i_b = 'dd'`

For example:

```
FUNCTION Get_result(
      p_i_a IN VARCHAR2,
      p_i_b IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN T_table Pipelined
AS
    Vrow R_list;
      BEGIN
        FOR rec IN cursor(p_i_a, p_i_b)
        LOOP
          Vrow.col_1 := Rec.col_1 ;
          Vrow.col_2 := Rec.col_2 ;
          pipe row (vRow);
        END LOOP;
      END Get_result;

FUNCTION Func1(
      p_i_a IN VARCHAR2,
      p_i_b IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN Get_result(p_i_a, p_i_b);

FUNCTION Func2(
      p_i_a IN VARCHAR2,
      p_i_b IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN Get_result(p_i_a, p_i_b);
```

Do you have any ideas. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand... why do you need Func1 and Func2 if they're just calling Get_result? Did you mean to have `"aa"` etc in double-quotes, as identifiers - if so what is the significance?

Comment: The main purpose is to save code. Whether I call Func1 or Func2 or some other function, they should always call our generic function Get_result with the specified parameters.

Comment: Why doesn't everything call the generic function directly? How does it save code to add lots of wrapper functions? Do the double-quotes imply you're trying to specify the *column names* the cursor returns, rather than values for something actually called col1 and col2? Even though the record type is (and has to be) based on those fixed columns?

Comment: because the real functions which call Get_result are with different names

Comment: The parameters in the functions are string values, which are saved as values in the columns in the database table

Comment: OK, so the double-quotes were a mistake, it seems. That doesn't explain why you want to have functions that do the same thing but are dedicated to specific argument values, rather than everything just calling Get_result directly. The only thing I can think of is you have a look-up table with lots of categories and want category-specific function names, perhaps. Even in that scenario, what is the problem calling Get_result from Func1?

Comment: I want to use something like this : Func1('aa', 'bb') {   return Get_result('aa', 'bb') }  .......  Func2('cc', 'dd') {   return Get_result('cc', 'dd') } Is it possible?

Comment: p_i_a and p_i_b are different string values in two columns in the db.

Comment: For example col1 contains contries, and col2 contains people

Comment: How does calling `Func1('aa','bb')` and `Func2('cc','dd')` differ from calling `Func1('cc','dd')` and `Func2('aa','bb')`?  They all just end up calling `Get_Result('aa','bb')` or `Get_Result('cc','dd')`

Comment: Can you better describe the problem you are trying to solve with this or the use case to which it applies?  Try including some sample tables and data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you just want to call your generic function from another function with a different name:

```
FUNCTION Func1(
      p_i_a IN VARCHAR2,
      p_i_b IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN T_table Pipelined
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN Get_result(p_i_a => p_i_a, p_i_b => p_i_b);
END;
```

But that seems trivial so maybe I'm still not understanding what issue you really want to do. Having the wrapper functions take the same arguments and just pass them through to the generic function seems unnecessary and redundant, since the callers need to know all the argument values anyway.

This pattern *might* make some sense if, say, your `col1` was a category (countries, people) and `col2` was actual values in that category, and you want a wrapper function that hides that; but then the function would be named appropriately and wouldn't need to be passed the first argument; something like:

```
FUNCTION Get_country(
      p_i_b IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN T_table Pipelined
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN Get_result(p_i_a => 'country', p_i_b => p_i_b);
END;
```

But that doesn't seem to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Package specification:

```
Type r_record
IS
  Record
  (
    col_1 Table.col_1 %Type ,
    col_2 Table.col_1 %Type );
Type T_table
IS
  TABLE OF r_record;
  CURSOR cur (p_i_a IN VARCHAR2, p_i_b IN VARCHAR2)
  IS
    SELECT col_1, col_2 
    FROM Table
    WHERE col_1= p_i_a 
    AND col_2= p_i_b 

  FUNCTION Func1()
    RETURN T_table Pipelined;

  FUNCTION Func2()
    RETURN T_table Pipelined;
```

Package body:

```
  FUNCTION Get_result(
      p_i_a IN VARCHAR2,
      p_i_b IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN T_table Pipelined
AS
    Vrow R_list;
      BEGIN
        FOR rec IN cursor(p_i_a, p_i_b)
        LOOP
          Vrow.col_1 := Rec.col_1 ;
          Vrow.col_2 := Rec.col_2 ;
          pipe row (vRow);
        END LOOP;
      END Get_result;

  FUNCTION Func1()
    RETURN T_table Pipelined
AS
    Vrow R_list;
      BEGIN
        FOR rec IN cursor('aa', 'bb')
        LOOP
          Vrow.col_1 := Rec.col_1 ;
          Vrow.col_2 := Rec.col_2 ;
          pipe row (vRow);
        END LOOP;
      END Func1;

  FUNCTION Func2()
    RETURN T_table Pipelined
AS
    Vrow R_list;
      BEGIN
        FOR rec IN cursor('cc', 'dd')
        LOOP
          Vrow.col_1 := Rec.col_1 ;
          Vrow.col_2 := Rec.col_2 ;
          pipe row (vRow);
        END LOOP;
      END Func2;
```